# I can't filter by year with form in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/ofertas/filtro-ofertas/filtro-ofertas.component.ts

Y need to filter the table by year

[image: filter]

But when I change the default selection (2021) I get always the same error

```
oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum.getFullYear is not a function
```

when any value in the form changes

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .subscribe(valores => {
    this.ofertas = this.ofertasOriginal;
    this.buscarOfertas(valores);
    this.escribirParametrosBusquedaEnURL();
  });

 buscarOfertas(valores: any) {
  if (valores.años) {
   this.ofertas = 
  this.ofertas.filter(oferta=>oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum.getFullYear()==valores.años);
  }
```

I simply compare the year of the field of type date fechaPresentacionFulcrum with the selected value

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you've already confirmed that `fechaPresentacionFulcrum` is not undefined and that its type is actually `Date`?

Comment: @AldinBradaric you guess well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
this.ofertas.filter(oferta=>new Date(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum).getFullYear()==valores.años);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like that

```
  buscarOfertas(valores: any) {
    if (valores.años) {
      console.log(valores.años);     

      this.ofertas = this.ofertas.filter(oferta=>Number(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum.toString().substring(0, 4))==valores.años);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).